# How does "template" and "include" differ in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

How does "template" and "include" keywords differ in helm. Both seem to be used to render template parameters

Answer (score 44):

`template` is part of the core Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language.  It always renders its results to the template output; it does not produce a value and its result cannot be captured in a variable or included in a pipeline.

`include` is a [Helm extension](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function).  It captures the template output and returns it as a string.  Its result can be used the same way as any other support function call.  `include` is not a "keyword" or "action" or "special form", from the point of view of the templating language it is an ordinary extension function.

If you're unsure, in the context of a Helm chart, `include` is usually not wrong.

The most important place where this difference matters is where you have a block that produces a YAML fragment, and you need to indent it.  Helm includes an [`indent`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#indent) function that can do this, but it needs a string to do this, so you need to use `include` and not `template` here.

```
{{- define "foo.labels" -}}
foo: bar
{{ end -}}

metadata:
  labels:
{{ include "foo.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
{{ include "foo.labels" . | indent 8 }}
```

For a more direct example, consider a template that just quotes its parameter.  If you call this with `template`, the template pipeline syntax applies to the template parameter.  If you call it with `include`, it applies to the result of the template call.  Combining this with `indent`, there's a visible difference whether you see the indentation inside or outside the quotes.

```
{{ define "quote" }}{{ quote . }}{{ end }}

{{/* "hello" is indented, then "  hello" is quoted */}}
Template: {{ template "quote" "hello" | indent 2 }}

{{/* "hello" is quoted, then '"hello"' is indented */}}
Include:  {{ include "quote" "hello" | indent 2 }}
```

```
Template: "  hello"

Include:    "hello"
```